# Make repeating character vector values

Tags: r, repeat

Hey there everyone just getting started with R, so I decided to make some data up with the eventual goal of superimposing it on top of a map.

Before I can get there I'm trying to add a name to my data to sort by Province.

```
Drugs <- c("Azin", "Prolof")
Provinces <- c("Ontario", "British Columbia", "Quebec")
Gender <- c("Female", "Male")

raw <- c(10,16,8,20,7,12,13,11,9,7,14,7)
yomom <- matrix(raw, nrow = 6, ncol = 2)
colnames(yomom) <- Drugs
bro <- data.frame(Gender, yomom)
idunno <- data.frame(Provinces, bro)
```

The first problem I've encountered is that the provinces vector is repeating, I'm not sure how to make it look like [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/100XrMpEL3atnhiGaCD8kw0X8SE33zBx1xCTnrw_JBOM/edit?usp=sharing) in R. I'm basically trying to get it to skip a row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
idunno <- data.frame(Provinces=rep(Provinces,each=2), bro)
idunno
#          Provinces Gender Azin Prolof
# 1          Ontario Female   10     13
# 2          Ontario   Male   16     11
# 3 British Columbia Female    8      9
# 4 British Columbia   Male   20      7
# 5           Quebec Female    7     14
# 6           Quebec   Male   12      7
```

Read the documentation on `rep(...)`

Comment: +1 for the reference to the documentation (@user3900661, type `?rep` in R)

Comment: Thank you, and I will, did not realize that function existed.